# How to directly mutate javascript object containing JSON rather than using array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6

With a `source` JSON file below, I wish to read in , and apply the delta from a ```changes.JSON file.  There is a more elegant way using direction mutation than reading into an array and writing back out. Curious how to do the direct mutation on the object and merge the changes into the source?  The changes.json file has "action" and "payload" keys to direction operations on changes.json

source.json

```
 {
    "users" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "Dave Mustaine"
      }
    ]
  }
```

changes.json

```
{
    "users": [{
        "action": "add",
        "payload": [{
                "id": "2",
                "name": "James Hetfield"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

becomes this:

```
{
    "users" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "Dave Mustaine"
      },
      {
        "id" : "2",
        "name": "James Hetfield"
    ]
}
```

In my noob implementation I have all the logic written to parse out the action and payload, but currently writing into an array, but I think that is unnecessary and there is a more elegant way to just directly mutate the object and then stringify it and write out the updated json.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Stream in source file
    fs.readFile('./' + inputFile, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let input = JSON.parse(data);
        //console.log(input);
    });

    // Stream in changes file
    fs.readFile('./' + changesFile, 'utf-8', (err, jsonString) => {
    if (err)  {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            try {
                const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
            
                const array = [];

                Object.entries(data).map(([key, [{ action,  payload }]]) => {
                    switch (key) {
                        case 'users': {
                            if (action === 'add') {
                                console.log("it's an add");
                                array.push([`${key}`, `${payload}`]);
                            }
                        break;
                        }

                     case 'playlists': {
                        if (action === 'add') {
                            console.log("it's an add");
                            array.push([`${key}`, `${payload}`]);
                        }
                            break;
                        }
                    
                        case 'songs': {
                        if (action === 'add') {
                            console.log("it's an add");
                            array.push([`${key}`, `${payload}`]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                 }
                });
                
                console.log(array);

            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Error parsing JSON', err);
            }
        }
    }); 

    // after we have merged changes and source we need to write out
    fs.appendFile('./' + outputFile, JSON.stringify(array, null, 2), err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('File sucessfully written');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just a heads up, when you do `JSON.parse(`, it's no longer JSON, it's a javascript object..

Comment: Your payload is an array? Could you demonstrate your `delete` and `update` cases in your example too?

Comment: Thanks, yes, just wondering how once I parse, instead of manipulating through arrays, how do I just apply changes from another json file into the original?  Just need to munge together.  Been looking everywhere on how to do this?

Comment: Sorry, Nick, I haven't written them yet.  I thought I should get just add working first.  For update, I am guessing you would do an ID compare and if it's the same, overwrite, and delete, just grab the id and nix it and rewrite out.  It actually ends up being quite complex what I have stumbled into coding

Comment: Surely there is way once you parse the JSON data from the source, and then parse the data from the changes a way to insert the changes into the source more elegantly than looping over everything and writing to arrays and manipulating, maybe not...maybe it is actually as complex as I am making it.  It's like command-line CRUD or something.

Comment: Your  source object and your changes object don't even have the same structure.  There is clearly NO way to do this automatically.  You're going to have to write code that loops over both and inserts.  There is no automatic way to do this.  And, JSON is a plain text format.  Once the JSON has been parsed, it is NOT JSON any more - it's a Javascript object.  I'd suggest you fix the title of your question to NOT refer to JSON because what you're trying to operate on here are javascript objects.